# Link Lookup Table to Account Name Field

Tags: dynamics-crm, office365

In CRM Online I need to link the Account Name field in the Account entity to a lookup table of imported and approved company names.  The goal is to require users to pick from an approved list instead of letting them make up a company account name.   I know there is an Account Name lookup in Contacts which uses existing Account Name records, but I need the lookup in the Account entity.  Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

CRM renders a Lookup control for a [1:N relationship](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531171.aspx#BKMK_CreateEditN1Relationships). What you are trying achieve would fall more into a data validation scenario where users can enter account names from a pre-set list of names.

You can leverage a new event introduced in CRM 2016 - [addOnKeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_addOnKeyPress) which can be easily used to build an [autocomplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607648.aspx)  feature which would be more inline with what you are trying to achieve. If a user doesn't "pick" a value instead types anything in disregarding the autocomplete use [attribute control's setNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_setnotification) to set an error message which would invalidate the save preventing the user from saving the record.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a different entity as LookupTable, then create a relationship between Account ans the Lookup Table entity. After that you can use that entity as Lookup attribute in Account entity

Comment: Why create an entity just to hold account names and create a relationship back to the account entity which signifies nothing? Lookups are fancy I agree, but do not create relationships which are not domain driven. Also it would not suit the OP's requirement of customizing the out of the box account name control on the page.